# Importing a python module built in Tkinter (which is reliant on images) from a different directory

Tags: python, tkinter, sys

I am trying to import a python program from within another python program, however these are not in the same directories, and so I am using this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Project")
import Maths
```

This works, and it opens the program. However, the problem I am having with this is that the program I am importing relies on some images and files that don't seem to get loaded (which prevents the program from running properly). These files are placed in

`C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Project/resources`

**What I've Tried**

I have tried placing my program that I am importing into the same directory as the files it relies on, but this came with the same error as shown here:

```
couldn't open "resources/bg.png": no such file or directory
```

**So my question is - how can I fix the issue I describe above?**

Comment: How to do it _without_ tkinter? If you don't know the answer to that, how do you know using tkinter related at all?

Comment: Edited to show the error

Comment: (which is from tkinter)

Comment: "couldn't open "resources/bg.png": no such file or directory"  Provide a /complete/path/to/the_file to tell the computer where to find it.  Computers have no psychic powers.

Comment: This does not help, as I do not want the directory to be absolute in my code. It works when I run Maths from the directory it's in, however.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to turn Maths module into an import package. Put it inside your working folder, in a subfolder. Put an empty `__init__.py` in that subfolder to make Maths a package. You can now import it as usual from any module that is started from the working folder. To solve the error you'll have to abstract the resources location inside the Maths code. Try using `pkgutil.get_data(package, resource)` to get the contents of those files.
See [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html?highlight=pkgutil#module-pkgutil) docs, in the page bottom.